# Android, Twitter, 'FOLLOW US'

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am building an android application and I am stuck at one place. I have integrated Twitter in my app using twitter4j, signpost apis. I am successful in writing code for putting text in user profile but I also want the user to follow my app when they click 'follow us on twitter' button.

Can anybody give me reference or guidance of writing such code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is [createFriendship()](http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendshipMethods.html#createFriendship%28long%29)

You can see how it is [used here](http://code.google.com/p/android-hackathon-in-fukuoka/source/browse/trunk/sodefuri/src/jp/jagfukuoka/sodefuri/TimeLineActivity.java?spec=svn167&r=167)

2016 Edit: Google code svn is broken and twitter 4j has moved
http://twitter4j.org/en/api-support.html

Comment: Thanks Reno..it helped a lot!!

Comment: @Avishek twitter4j seems to have moved please see http://twitter4j.org/en/api-support.html