# Android Intent to follow Twitter user?

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

In my About screen, I would like to allow the user to easily "Follow" my Twitter account.

I was hoping that existing Twitter apps would support some kind of Intent for this. I would rather not use the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752387/android-twitter-follow-us) because this requires authentication, AFAICT.

If the user has already installed, for example, the official Twitter app, then it is better for any authentication to be done within that app, if necessary.

I have previously tried contacting those behind the official Twitter app, but received no response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question, but I believe here is now a better way. Use the Web Intent.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button/web-intent

Basically just use an ACTION_VIEW with the url: https://twitter.com/intent/follow?user_id=<theuserid>

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This correctly uses the Twitter app if installed, and browser if not, so the advantage is we **no longer** need to do something like: `try {
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=" + twitterName)));
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/" + twitterName)));
}`

Comment: As a side note, I would say https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=<screen name> is a clearer example, to avoid people thinking `theuserid` is a twitter handle.

Comment: @MarkCarter screen_name IS clearer, however the documentation states that screen names can change while the user id cannot. So when possible I would use the user_id to make sure it never breaks.

Comment: BTW, if you are publishing to Amazon Appstore, you cannot use https://twitter.com/intent/follow... because if the Twitter app is not installed, the user will be directed to a Twitter web page which shows a link to the Google Play Store (to install Twitter app)

Answer (score 5):

I just ended up using the standard http-based Intent:

Action:

```
android.intent.action.VIEW
```

Data:

```
http://twitter.com/mytwitterusername
```

The user can then choose whether to open the Intent in the official Twitter app (or whatever) and easily Follow mytwitterusername from there.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/mytwitterusername")); MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 1):

If the user has installed official twitter app and is logged in, I don't think twitter4j will ask for the authentication again. I have previously worked with twitter4j and facebook api and none of them asked for authentication if user is already logged in...

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. It would be nice if there was just a simple Intent though. At least it would avoid having to use a 3rd party API.

Comment: right, but Why twitter will allow any one to interact with their system without authentication ? Even if you just want to follow someone you still need to be a valid user...thats it!!

Comment: But if the Twitter app authenticates the user then it would need to somehow expose this (via broadcast receiver, intent filter etc) for other apps to take advantage of it, no?

Comment: Nope. That way I could check if somebody is logged in Twitter and start follwing random people, retweeting random tweets or tweeting whatever I want.