# How to integrate Twitter follow button in Android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to integrate a twitter **FOLLOW US** button in my android app. So that if user clicks the button, he/she start following my application page on twitter. I downloaded **Twitter4J** for it. But I am confused how and where to start with. I have seen a lot article on **sending a tweet to an account** but nobody mentions any thing related to **FOLLOW**. Can anybody please guide the steps I should follow to create this follow button.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, Twitter, 'FOLLOW US'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752387/android-twitter-follow-us)

Comment: Did you solve this issue, please help this one..

Answer (score 0):

You have to call **[createFriendship](http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendshipMethods.html#createFriendship%28long%29)** function for this.

For the coding help , [Here is help for how to integrate that](http://code.google.com/p/android-hackathon-in-fukuoka/source/browse/trunk/sodefuri/src/jp/jagfukuoka/sodefuri/TimeLineActivity.java?spec=svn167&r=167)

Probably duplicating SO Question [Android, Twitter, 'FOLLOW US'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7752387/582571)